# ruby on rails retains the same value for a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    simp_ = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.gender.blank?
       load './bayes.rb'
       b_obj= Bayes.new
       simp_.gender = b_obj.predict(@user.height, @user.weight)
       predict_(simp_)
    else
      if @user.save
        redirect_to @user
      else
        @title = "Train"
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
 ...

  def predict_(_user)
    @user = _user
    render 'predicted' ( I am printing @user.gender here)
  end
```

Everything works fine and I am able to use user defined class bayes as well. The problem is that the value stored in 'simp_.gender' always remain the same, no matter what my function returns. This is causing a lot of problems.

How should I handle this?

Arun

Comment: I suspect the setter method for gender attribute does not work well, did you verify the same? You should also verify that predict method of Bayes class returns the expected value for gender attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First double-check the value returned by `b_obj.predict`:

```
gender = b_obj.predict(@user.height, @user.weight)
logger.info "GENDER: #{gender}"
simp_.gender = gender
```

Try it, then look at the log. If you still need help, edit your question and add information on what was written to the log.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. I checked the log there were some NaN values up there. Sorted them out, works well :)

Comment: Glad this helped you sort the problem out! An upvote would be appreciated.